# Migrating SSL certificates in IIS

Tags: iis, website, certificate

A recent development has occurred where a client has requested to move their website from the current hosting server to our in house servers. This website has an SSL associated with it. Can an SSL be migrated, or copied over to a different server to avoid purchasing a new SSL for the website?

Comment: What version of IIS is it?

Comment: IIS 7 and I may have another case for IIS 6

Comment: Yes, you can export an SSL key from IIS and import it into another server.

Comment: Do you know of any sites that can "coach" me through that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't do this all that often so I don't remember if the cert has to be marked as exportable for this to work, but you've got nothing to lose by trying it:

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm

Comment: Yes. The certificate has to be marked as exportable.

Comment: When do you mark the certificate as exportable? Is this before installing it?

Comment: @GMitch Yes, IIS ask for it when installing/importing.

Comment: @GMitch - You mark it as exportable when you're generating the certificate or when you're importing the certificate. What it's really doing is just marking the private key portion of the cert as exportable.